# Angular js ng-repeat animation in ng-included issue in chrome

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to use animation of ng-repeat which is inside ng-included template; I see that it works fine in firefox but doesn't in chrome. For example:

template.html

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in myArray" class="repeated-item"/>
  </ul>
```

main.html

```
<body>
      <div ng-include="template.html"></div>
  </body>
```

Anybody here has faced problem with this?

Comment: just clear your cache in chrome... may be it works...

Comment: Yeah I did, but no chance to get it work yet. But let's say I have tried another ng-repeat underneath ng-include; it works just for the outside one. I am kinda stuck now.